# Dio invalid status code of 301. Tried many things but it doesn't work

Tags: flutter, http-status-code-301, dio, bad-request

This is a reference to how the data is supposed to look:

[image]

This is how I did it:

```
Future<Response> post() async {

    try {

      //---
      final Response response = await _dio.post(
        "/api/verifyPhone",
        data: {"name": "Ali Khaled", "phone": "01111111111"},
      );
      //---

      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Which results in `DioException [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 301.`

I tried using `jsonEncode()` and `headers: {"Accept":"application/json"}`, but nothing seems to work.

I would really appreciate your help!

### Edit

get() requests works just fine so, I think the problem is related to the data passed into the post request?

### Edit 2

Deleting the data is supposed to result in "error 405, name is required", but that also didn't change the "error 301" that I get.
So, the problem isn't in the data passed either?!!

Comment: your url is invalid in _dio.post()

Comment: update this to-  _dio.post('https:/imagdsoft.ahmedshəwky.fun/api/verifyPhone' ,...). Then try again

Comment: base url is passed in initialization, and get requests works just fine so, I think the problem is related to the data passed into the post request? but where is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone facing the same problem

I was able to solve it by changing URL address from ***http*** to ***https***.

`get()` requests worked, because it worked just fine with the http link, and `Error 301` indicates a redirection, So the problem was definitely in the link.